# Alter new and existing session Command Timeout value

Tags: connection, sql-server-2008-r2, timeout, session, command

My first post so please me...

I’m a self-taught DBA in a manufacturing environment full of engineers who like to fiddle.
Although I have not given them sysadmin or any explicit extra rights I have an issue with some engineers running ‘killer’ queries, some very io intensive.
This would not be an issue normally given the default Command Timeout of 30 seconds for connections, but some of these engineers have purchased SQL Developer, purely for the autocomplete feature, and of course this by default connects them with an infinite ‘CommandTimeout’.

What I would like to do, in some way, is to alter either/or new connections/sessions and set their CommandTimeout to something more reasonable, maybe less than 30 seconds.
For new connections, I envision its some sort of Database Trigger that then executes a command under their context?
Existing connections, maybe something horrible in the system tables?

Answer (score 0):

The command timeout is a client-side option. Unfortunately you cannot set it globally on the server. Depending on how your application is programmed and configured, you may be able to force this from that end.